# Rewrite PK and related FK based on an oracle sequence

Tags: oracle, liquibase

I want to migrate a subset of customer data from one shared database environment to another shared database environment.  I use hibernate and have quite a few ID and FK_ID columns which are auto generated from an oracle sequence.

I have a liquibase change log that I exported from jailer which has the customer specific data.

I want to be able to rewrite all of the sequence ID columns so that they don't clash with what's already in the target database.

I would like to avoid building something that my company has to manage, and would prefer to upstream this to liquibase.

Is anyone aware of anything within liquibase that might be a good place to start.

I would like to either do this on the liquidbase xml before passing it to 'update' command, or as part of the update command itself.  Ideally as part of the update command itself.

I am aware that I would need to make liquibase aware of which columns are PK sequence columns and the related FK columns.  The database structure does have this all well defined, so I should be able to read this into the update process.

Alternatively I had thought I could use the extraction model csv from jailer

Jailer - http://jailer.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that for one-time data migrations like this, Liquibase is not the best tool. It is really better for schema management rather than data management. I think that an ETL tool such as Pentaho would be a better solution.

Comment: My original question should have been more precise with the word migration.  It's actually a copy of customer data, the only thing that needs to change is the PK (and related FK) columns that are sourced from a oracle sequence.  I needed to be able to rewrite these columns with a new sequence value that would not conflict.  I also needed it to be re-runnable as we will be moving other customer data to different databases in future (based on version upgrades, sizing requirements, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to figure it out for myself with the command line 'update' command of liquibase by using a custom change exec listener.

1) I pushed a MR to liquibase to allow registration of a change exec listener

2) I implemented my own change exec listener that intercepts each insert statement and rewrites each FK and PK field to one that is not as yet allocated in the target database.  I achieve this by using a oracle sequence.  In order to avoid having to go back to the database each time for a new sequence, I implemented my own version of the hibernate sequence caching

https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/pull/505

https://github.com/pellcorp/liquibase-extensions

This turned out to be quite a generic solution and in concert with some fixes upstreamed to jailer to improve the liquibase export support its a very viable and reusable solution.

Basic workflow is:

1) Export a subset of data from source db using jailer to liquibase xml

2) Run the liquibase update command, with the custom exec change listener against the target.

3) TODO Run the jailer export on the target db and compare with the original source data.